# How is that in PHP you can use a variable that has not been defined yet?

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I'm working on this script and I'm trying to modify the payment system a bit to integrate authorize.net.  Only problem is I need to find the declaration for some variables that I cannot seem to find yet are used throughout the script.  How is this possible and is there a way to find out where they are declared?

Comment: Because PHP will define a variable the first time it's referenced if it doesn't already exist: while it might be considered good practise to define a variable in advance of using it, it isn't mandatory

Comment: ok makes sense...but what if the variable is an array and the code references indexes of the array without defining any of them yet?

Comment: @date yes you can do that in php, array are very flexible

Comment: Same principle applies..... up the error level to display warnings and notices, and you might get some clues about what is and isn't defined

Comment: im using phpstorm and the command "cntrl + click" seems to not find the declaration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: PHPStorm > right click the directory / project / find in path -> enter desired  text.

Comment: OK so let me ask you this...how is this logically possible:  $paypal['status'] = 1.   When $paypal hasn't been assigned and $paypal['status'] has never been assigned? By any chance the $paypal array being manipulated by reference anywhere?  Cause thats the only other way i know that can manipulate a variable w/o declaring it...get me?

Comment: and if a variable has never been assigned anything its value is '' by default correct?

Comment: It's a programming language.  Anything is "logically" possible, if the language designers allow it.  Variables could be created at random, with random values, if people thought that would be useful.

Comment: ok keeping with respect to php..

Comment: at the example you brought at least some where $paypal=array();

Comment: exactly my point!  theres has to be a place where $paypal has been modified through reference or (re)declaration...otherwise how are those specific indexes with being initialized with values not default to php automatically assigning them...

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I figured it out.  The only other way to instantiate/declare a variable without explicitly doing so is by PHP's variable variables feature.  What was happening was the variables were being set by variable variables from a database query result.

Even though I should've provided more information/code possibly, someone should've have mentioned variable variables and assignment by reference.

Comment: Sorry, we don't have a crystal ball :)